# Finishing Calendar table <tr>, <td> with php code

Tags: php, html

When in Notepad++ anything in `""` inside php in block will not display and finish the table.  So the `echo "<tr>";` turns grey and does not finish the table. Any suggestions?

```
<table border='1'>
     <tr>
            <td><input type='button' value='<' name='previousebutton' onclick="goLastMonth(<?php echo $month.",".$year?>)"></td>
            <td colspan='5'> <?php echo $monthName.", ".$year ?> </td>
            <td><input type='button' value='>' name='nextbutton'onclick="goNextMonth(<?php echo $month.",".$year?>)" ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='50px'>Sun</td>
            <td width='50px'>Mon</td>
            <td width='50px'>Tue</td>
            <td width='50px'>Wed</td>
            <td width='50px'>Thu</td>
            <td width='50px'>Fri</td>
            <td width='50px'>Sat</td>
        </tr>
        <?php
            echo "<tr>";

          for($i = 1; $i < $numDays+1; $i++ , $counter++){
                $timeStamp = strtotime("$year-$month-$i");
                if($i == 1) {
                    $firstDay = date("w", $timeStamp);
                    for($j = 0; $j < $firstDay; $j++, $counter++) {

                        echo "<td>$nbsp;</td>";             
                    }
                }
                if($counter % 7 == 0) {
                    echo "</tr><tr>";
                }
          }

          echo "</tr>";
          ?>
    </table>
```

Comment: what are your parameter values you used in this script looks like? $numDays, $counter etc?

Comment: <body>
  <?php
  if(isset($_GET['day'])){
  $day = $_GET['day'];
  }else{
  $day = date("j"); 
  }
  if(isset($_GET['month'])){
  $month = $_GET['month'];
  }else{
  $month = date("n");
  }
  if(isset($_GET['year'])){
  $year = $_GET['year']; 
  }else{
  $year = date("Y"); 
  }
    
  //calender variable
  $currentTimeStamp = strtotime("$year-$month-$day");
  $monthName = date("F", $currentTimeStamp);
  $numDays = date("t" , $currentTimeStamp);
  $counter = 0;
  ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified some of your code:

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_GET['day'])){ $day = $_GET['day']; }else{ $day = date("j"); } 
    if(isset($_GET['month'])){ $month = $_GET['month']; }else{ $month = date("n"); } 
    if(isset($_GET['year'])){ $year = $_GET['year']; }else{ $year = date("Y"); } 
    //calender variable 
    $currentTimeStamp = strtotime("$year-$month-$day"); 
    $monthName = date("F", $currentTimeStamp); 
    $numDays = date("t" , $currentTimeStamp); 
    $counter = 1; 
    $day = date('d', $currentTimeStamp);
    $firstDay = date('w', strtotime("{$year}-{$month}-01"));
?>
<table border='1'>
     <tr>
            <td><input type='button' value='<' name='previousebutton' onclick="goLastMonth(<?php echo $month.",".$year?>)"></td>
            <td colspan='5'> <?php echo $monthName.", ".$year ?> </td>
            <td><input type='button' value='>' name='nextbutton'onclick="goNextMonth(<?php echo $month.",".$year?>)" ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='50px'>Sun</td>
            <td width='50px'>Mon</td>
            <td width='50px'>Tue</td>
            <td width='50px'>Wed</td>
            <td width='50px'>Thu</td>
            <td width='50px'>Fri</td>
            <td width='50px'>Sat</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <?php for($i = 0; $i < $firstDay; $i++): ?>
                <td></td>
            <?php endfor; ?>
            <?php for($i = 1; $i <= $numDays; $i++): ?>
                <?php if($day == $i): ?>
                    <td><strong><?php echo $i ?></strong></td>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <td><?php echo $i ?></td>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if(($i + $firstDay) % 7 == 0): ?>
                    </tr><tr>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endfor; ?>
            <?php for($i = 0; ($i + $firstDay + $numDays) % 7 != 0; $i++): ?>
                <td></td>
            <?php endfor; ?>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: You have made my day @Jaya.  That fixed my problem and I have learned something. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the alternate control structure syntax for this, although (in my opinion) it can make some code harder to read:

```
<?php for($i = 1; $i < $numDays+1; $i++ , $counter++){
            $timeStamp = strtotime("$year-$month-$i");
            if($i == 1) {
                $firstDay = date("w", $timeStamp);
                for($j = 0; $j < $firstDay; $j++, $counter++): ?>
                    <td>$nbsp;</td>
                <?php endfor; ?>         
            }
            if($counter % 7 == 0): ?>
               </tr><tr>
            <?php endif; ?>
      }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks.  It does seem to confuse things a bit.  And when I tried using it still did not complete the table.  But helped my thought process.

Comment: Try this:
    <tr>
         <?php
          for($i = 1; $i < $numDays+1; $i++ , $counter++){
                $timeStamp = strtotime("$year-$month-$i");
                if($i == 1) {
                    $firstDay = date("w", $timeStamp);
                    for($j = 0; $j < $firstDay; $j++, $counter++): ?>
                        <td>$nbsp;</td>          
                    <?php endfor; ?>
                }
                if($counter % 7 == 0): ?>
                    </tr><tr>
                <?php endif; ?>
          }
          ?>
          </tr>

Comment: I will have to play with that because it keeps giving me syntax errors at my closing tags.  I will work on the format and let you know.